# how to assign an array to an Observable type interface in angular

Tags: angular, interface, observable

The problem is I want to assign a value on a observable type interface. But I don't know how to do that.

```
export interface LocalConsultationCachingModel {
  cache: ConsultationModel[];
  httpPromise: Observable<ConsultationModel[]>;
}
```

I want to assign on `httpPromise: Observable<ConsultationModel[]>;
}`

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Assign an array to httpPromise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set value to an observable you can just use `of` operator from RxJS.
It'll emit your value then emits a complete notification.

```
let localConsultation : LocalConsultationCachingModel = {
   cache: [...],
   httpPromise: of([...])
}
```